# Can I use 1.1.1.1 for public websites and still be able to access local computers on my LAN

Tags: dns, hostname

I want to use Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 DNS to surf the internet for its privacy, but I still want to be able to refer local computers by machine name instead of having to remember IP addresses.

Comment: That really depends on what you are using the resolve local names. mDNS? NetBIOS Name Services? Try using `nslookup` to resolve some.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly yes. It depends on where want to configure your upstream DNS server, which could be on your PC, or your router. By default your PC will use the router and it will use your Internet Service Proders's DNS (ISP).

```
PC --- Router_DNS --- ISP_DNS --- internet
```

If you have some kind of more advanced home route, like dd-wrt, openwrt, pfsense, etc. , you can configure the upstream DNS 1.1.1.1 on that. It would also contain your home network DNS entries. This would then replace the DNS server supplied by your internet provider.

```
PC --- router_dns --x-- ISP_DNS 
          |
           ----------->1.1.1.1 --- internet
```

If you want to configure 1.1.1.1 directly into your computer, you would be bypassing where ever you currently have those local DNS entries defined. You would need to redefine them on your PC. I would recommend going the advanced router path.